# Elegant way to delete all rows in a matrix after a row breaks a rule [r]

Tags: r

I have a matrix where once a column value exceeds a certain value I want to delete all rows after that point. For example, if I want to remove all rows from the point a cell in the first column was greater than 2, I could do this:

```
original_matrix = matrix(c(1,2,3,2,5,6,7,8),nrow = 4)
processed_matrix = matrix(c(original_matrix,rep(0,length(original_matrix[,1]))),nrow = 4)

rule_broken = FALSE
for(i in 1:length(processed_matrix[,1])){
  if(processed_matrix[i,1]>2){
    rule_broken = TRUE
  }
  if(rule_broken){
    processed_matrix[i,3] = NA

  } else {
    processed_matrix[i,3] = 1
  }

}
resulting_matrix=na.omit(processed_matrix)
```

But it feels like a round about way to do it. Is there a more elegant way to detect a rule has been broken in a row, and then delete all rows from that point onward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by creating a logical vector by comparing the first column with 2 (`original_matrix[,1] > 2`), take the cumulative sum, the values that are 0's are those we wanted to keep.  So, negate (`!`) it to convert the 0's to TRUE and all others to FALSE, use that to subset the rows of 'original_matrix'

```
original_matrix[!cumsum(original_matrix[,1]>2),, drop = FALSE]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    5
#[2,]    2    6
```